# AMQP(RabbitMQ) Could not deserialize object, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, serialization, rabbitmq, classnotfoundexception, amqp

I want to implement a RabbitMq(AMQP) messaging in java SpringBoot, but when I receive the message it says that the messaGE could not be deserialize because I the class for the object that I supposed to receive was not found even if I have that class int the classpath.

**RabbitMqListener.java:**

```
@EnableRabbit
@Component
public class RabbitMqListener {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RabbitMqListener.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue2")
    public void processQueue1(Product message) {

        logger.info("Received from queue 2: " + message);
    }

}
```

**RabbitConfiguration.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RabbitConfiguration.class);
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }


    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue1() {

        return new Queue("queue1");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue2() {

        return new Queue("queue2");
    }

}
```

**SampleController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleController.class);

    @Autowired
    AmqpTemplate template;

    @RequestMapping("/emit")
    @ResponseBody
    String queue1() {
        logger.info("Emit to queue1");
        template.convertAndSend("queue1","Message to queue 1");
        return "Emit to queue 1";
    }
}
```

**Product.java:**

```
public class Product implements Serializable{

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private int stock;

    private int price;



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public Product() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", stock=" + stock +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**And the stacktrace:**

```
2016-07-11 09:34:02.840  WARN [order-service,,,] 4084 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:865) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358) [spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102) [spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086) [spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203) [spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not deserialize object type
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:82) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:110) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:185) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:173) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:118) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:102) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:88) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.productservice.model.Product
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:75) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter$1.resolveClass(SimpleMessageConverter.java:179) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:76) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 17 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: It looks like a Spring specific classpath issue and not related to amqp or rabbitMQ> Please revisit the project setup once again

Comment: Found the problem. The messaging is between two modules, in one module I had Person.java and in the other module I had another Person.java, to deserialize I needed exactly the same class so the solution is to make a new common module which contains Person.java and import it into receiver and into emitter modules.

Comment: @FlaviuCicio: you can also convert the message to json before sending and convert back to your object on receiving, if your requirements allow that. This way you have much more flexibility to create treat the data when they are received. Also, This technique could simplify your code as you will be sending and receiving just a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the code snippet you have registered jsonMessageConverter and at the same time you are making your Person.java serializable. You should  either use serialization or the json approach. Moreover the problem lies in the package structure of Person.java. I encountered the same problem, resolved it by taking same package structure for the object being transferred in producer and consumer. The reason behind this is that while serialization, java takes class name , package structure and other information into account, so at the consumer side we need to have the same package structure.I encountered the same problem while using  jsonMessageConverter. So from my viewpoint the solution to this problem is to package your message objects into a jar and add that jar as a dependency in your producer and consumer project.

Comment: had the same case. if you use on both sides the same structure it will work.

Comment: It's going to be as a god class if we make that object as a common dependency.

Comment: What if you want to consume the message from a non-java application?

Answer (score 5):

When you use `rabbitmq`, you shoud keep your class in the same name package,
such as : `com.xxx.entity.Order`. If class is in a different package like ``` com.xxx.consumer.entity.Order``com.xxx.producer.entity.Order ``` it will throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who came here from **IntelliJ** and still have not solved this or similar kind of `ClassNotFoundException` issue while working with **message queuing**; it is most likely that you are working on two, or more, different projects and, you may even have the projects under the same root but you are still getting this exception because these two, or more, projects are not set as modules of a single project in IntelliJ. Furthermore, to serialize and/or deserialize the objects RabbitMQ requires the same class, but you may have two similar looking classes in different projects.

To solve this issue, you can follow this trick:

1. Create a new empty project at the root folder that contains your "disjoint" projects.
2. IntelliJ will prompt you to import these projects into this empty project as modules; select the `pom.xml` or the `build.gradle` file to import them as such.
3. Press OK and the projects will be loaded under your previously empty project.
4. Now, all that's left is to group these modules. You can do this by following - [IntelliJ's Guide for Grouping Modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#group-by-qualified-names).
5. After grouping the modules you can (delete one, or more, of the classes from the different modules - leaving just one implementation of the class) import the required class from the required module by adding a Maven or Gradle dependency to the module.

*If you are using Maven then the dependency in you `pom.xml` file should look something like this:*

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```