# ClassNotFoundException in spring-rabbit depending on when consumer or producer is started

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring Boot with spring-amqp and RabbitMQ to send messages between two JVMs that I am running locally. Depending on the order that I start each app, I'll sometimes get a `ClassNotFoundException`. I have a multiproject setup like so:

```
- Project root
   - common (contains all events / messages that are sent)
   - server
   - client
```

When the server is started first, it waits for a message from the client. When the client is then started, it implements a `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` and sends a message to the server to signal that it is ready.

**Server listener:**

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues =  "server.${server.id}")
public class ServerListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerListener.class);

    @RabbitHandler
    public void onMessageReceived(@Payload ClientAvailableEvent event) {
        logger.info("Server: Received request from client ID = {}", event.getClientId());
    }
}
```

**Client Producer:**

```
@Component
public class ClientReadyProducer implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientReadyProducer.class);

    @Value("${client.id}")
    private String id;

    private final RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public EventBasedModuleRegistration(RabbitTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {    
        logger.info("Client initialized.");
        ClientAvailableEvent event = ClientAvailableEvent.from(id);
        template.convertSendAndReceive("server.exchange.all", "", event);
    }
}
```

When the server gets this message, the log blows up with an infinite number of stack traces, complaining that it can't find `ClientAvailableEvent`:

```
2017-01-30 09:30:22.610  WARN 63573 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler :  [][] Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:865)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not deserialize object type
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:185)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:173)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.event.ClientAvailableEvent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:74)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter$1.resolveClass(SimpleMessageConverter.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:76)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

However, I can get this exception to go away. With the client still running, if I restart the server, everything is fine and continues to work without an issue. I can restart the client, it will send another `ClientAvailableEvent`, and the server will happily deserialize it.

Here are my Spring classes:

**ServerConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class ServerConfiguration {
    @Value("${server.id}")
    public String id;

    @Bean
    public Queue serverQueue() {
        return new Queue("server." + id, false, true, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange serverExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("server.exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindingById() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(serverQueue()).to(serverExchange()).with(id);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange allServersExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("server.exchange.all");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindingToAll() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(serverQueue()).to(allServersExchange());
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange clientExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("client.exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(factory);
    }
}
```

**Client Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class ClientConfiguration {
    @Value("${client.id}")
    private String id;

    @Bean
    public Queue clientQueue() {
        return new Queue("client." + id, false, true, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange clientExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("client.exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindingById() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(clientQueue()).to(clientExchange()).with(id);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange clientExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("client.exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange allClientsExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("client.exchange.all");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindingToAll() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(clientQueue()).to(allClientsExchange());
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(factory);
    }
}
```

I originally found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300784/amqprabbitmq-could-not-deserialize-object-classnotfoundexception) that has a near-identical stacktrace, but the solution in that case was to put all of the common events / models in one project and include that project into both the server and client projects. However, I'm already doing that. I also tried using JSON to send the messages (by adding the following to both configurations) instead of the standard serialization:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter producerJsonMessageConverter(){
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJsonMessageConverter(){
    return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate configureRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(producerJsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}

@Override
public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(producerJsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

Using JSON resulted in a similar stacktrace complaining about the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Here are the relevant dependencies I'm using:

- Spring Boot v1.3.8.RELEASE
- Spring AMQP v1.5.6.RELEASE
- Spring Rabbit v1.5.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely some kind of `Classloader` problem - perhaps you somehow have two versions of that class on the classpath.

The simplest way I have found to debug issues like this is run the JVM with `-verbose` and monitor where the class is loaded from.

Compare the log between a run that works and one that does not.

I am not surprised you get the same issue with JSON because the fully qualified class name is passed in a header.

Also, do you have unique packages across your jars? You can get issues like this if you serve up the same package from different jars.

Comment: When it works, `-verbose` tells me that the class is found in a JAR from the Gradle build output in my workspace: [Loaded com.example.event.ClientAvailableEvent from file:/Users/nick/dev/tmp/spring-amqp-project/common/build/libs/common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]. That seems logical to me, since the class is also in my workspace, but I don't understand why it wouldn't be found on the first run. Maybe Gradle is overwriting it when I bootRun the client, since they're in the same project, or something similar is happening to the JAR.

Comment: That probably 'splains it - try running from the boot uber jar instead of `bootRun`, `The Spring Boot Gradle plugin also includes a bootRun task which can be used to run your application in an exploded form`.

Comment: Running from the uber JAR worked fine. Finally found it. There was a task in my Gradle build that ran before `:common:jar` that caused the JAR task to always be out of date, so every build would cause the common.jar to be rebuilt. For whatever reason, once the JAR was overwritten, even though it had the same classes, the JVM wouldn't load any classes from it.